# How do I select a range using a range variable and an offset of the same variable?

Tags: vba

I've always had trouble working with ranges in VBA. Can someone please explain how to acheive the following:

I have a range variable called **Source_Index** which holds a reference to a single cell.

I want to select a range of cells using Source_Index as the anchor point. In this example, I would like to select Source_Index and the adjacent six cells to the left of Source_Index.

The pseudocode would look something like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("Source_Index:Source_Index.Offset(0,-6)")
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test offset by yourself:

```
MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range("Source_Index").Offset(0,-1).Value
MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range("Source_Index").Offset(0,-2).Value
'...and so on
```

Also,this is the basic selection:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("H1", "B1").Select
```

Here is what you want:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("Source_Index", Range("Source_Index").Offset(0,-6)).Select
```

so you can imagine `"H1" = "Source_Index"` 
and `"B1" =Range("Source_Index").Offset(0, -6)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is returning an Application-defined or object-defined error. I tried it without the quotation marks surrounding the variables and got the same result.

Comment: I experimented with your response and the following worked.

ActiveSheet.Range(Source_Index, Source_Index.Offset(0, -6)).Select

Comment: @rueffy Nice!  I forgot left side should be negative

Comment: @rueffy If this has solved your issue, kindly set it as the accepted answer.